# Safely push Android App respository to GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio, github, repository, push

I'm new to **GitHub**, and I want to push my Android App repository to my remote repository.
I already generated a **signed bundle** for my app.

My question is: Does **Android Studio** generate any files inside the project directory that I shouldn't publicly share on Github?

Thanks in advance.